# How to return file that is in external domain? (spring boot / java)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm making spring boot web service that receives the request for file download.

The domain for this service is `a.com` and this service brings requested file from `b.com` domain.

**This service needs to request the file from external domain.**

I wanna know how to return response to the client for the file download request in this case.

The below code is the one that I made.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/downloadFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(String param) throws IOException {
    String testFileName = "https://www.google.co.jp/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
    URL url = new URL(testFileName);
    File file = new File(url.getFile());
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");

    Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .headers(headers)
    .contentLength(file.length())
    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
    .body(resource);
}
```

But it doesn't work due to file path.
Its path is displayed like this.

```
/Users/user/devel/acomapplication/https:/www.google.co.jp/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a HTTP client to download the file you want to proxy. Here is some example how you can do this. This example uses the Apache HTTP client 4.5.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/downloadFile", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ResponseEntity download(String param) throws IOException { 
    String testFileName = "https://www.google.co.jp/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" 
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(testFileName);

    request.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
    request.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
    request.setHeader("Expires", "0");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200) {
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentLength(file.length())
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
        .body(response.getEntity().getContent());
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Path path = Path.resolve(fileName).normalize();
Resource resource = new UrlResource(path.toUri());
```

Try using this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case need download whit my API, files **hosted in other** server.

In my case, **don't need use a HTTP client to download the file in a external URL**, I combined several answers and methods worked in previous code for files that were in my local server.

My code is:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity downloadFileExternalUrl() {
    try {
        String url = "http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        byte[] byteContent = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class).getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        InputStream resourceInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteContent);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "pdf-with-my-API_pdf-test.pdf")
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf;"))
                .contentLength(byteContent.length)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(resourceInputStream));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```